# How to use PHP in HTML for mySQL

Tags: php, python, html, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use php for the first time to connect to MySQL on the raspberry pi. Both the server and MySQL are running on the Pi and I want to tweak my index.html file to show some value that is in the data base. Normally for I would be able to do just that with pyton but I have no clue if I can do that with php. Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ziks</title>
<link href="CSS/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(Images/twe_background-1920x1080.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
<p><strong>Welcome to Ziks</strong></p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="box">
<p> Wishing every one a happy life! </p>
<form method="GET" action="ftp://47.55.90.215:21">
<input type="submit" value="Click here to view Disk">
</form>
<body>
<html> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
</body>
<div class="image"></div>
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5nb4b3g/n1127/szw160/szh160/hoc9b8578/hbw10/hfc754c29/cf100/hnc432f30/hcw2/fav0/fiv0/mqcfff/mqs4/mql25/mqw12/mqd78/mhcfff/mhs2/mhl5/mhw2/mhd78/hhcfff/hhs2/hhl50/hhw8/hmcfff/hms2/hml70/hmw8/hmr4/hscfff/hss3/hsl70/hsw3" frameborder="0" width="160" height="160"></iframe>
  <video width="400" controls>
<!--<source src="///smb://zikpc/f/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">-->
<!--<source src="///smb://zikpc/f/test.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->

<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This index.html file works fine. All I want to do is write some php in it to connect to MySQL. The current method I'm using in python is:

```
# External module imports
import time
import os
import datetime
import MySQLdb
os.system('sudo modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('sudo modprobe w1-therm')

# Connect to mysql
db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","zikmir","gforce","temp_database")
cursor=db.cursor()

while True:
  # Initialization
  sensor= "/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-011620ee98ee/w1_slave"
  # Open the file for sensor
  file = open(sensor) 
  # Read all of the text in the file. 
  text = file.read()
  # Close the file now that the text has been read. 
  file.close() 
  # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line.
  second_line = text.split("\n")[1]  
  # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0).
  temp_data = second_line.split(" ")[9]
  # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number.
  temp = float(temp_data[2:])
  # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
  temp = temp / 1000
  # Display time
  t= datetime.datetime.now()
  print t,temp
  # Push data into mySQL
  sql = "INSERT INTO time_temp VALUES(now(),%s)"
  cursor.execute (sql,(temp,))
  db.commit()
  # Wait 5 seconds
  time.sleep(5)
```

My question is how would I be able to do this in php within the index.html file? Any help would be appreciated!
[This is my website](http://www.ziks.ca)

Comment: So the question is how to run queries with PHP? You should use PDO or mysqli for that. The queries should be parameterized if taking input.

Comment: @chris85 I have no clue what those are! Isn't there a simpler way or perhaps an example how to read a column from MySQL?

Comment: Can you trim this down to something more minimal? There's video, FTP, HTML, PHP, Python, MySQL and probably other things going on in this code.

Comment: @tadman sorry for the messy code, you can perhaps ignore all that and consider a simple new html file with nothing in it. All I want is to be able to retrieve data from MySQL.

Comment: This is pretty close to asking for a tutorial, which is off-topic. I'd have a look at something like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) if you have no idea where to start. It'll set you in the right direction.

Comment: Here are the manuals, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php You need to create a connection, then you can query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLi Object-Oriented

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

MySQLi Procedural

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

PDO

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices. The simplest, IMHO, would be something like the following.

Rename your index.html file to index.php (make sure that your web server looks for index.php as well as index.html and index.htm).

Your index.php would then be modified to look something like this:

```
<?php
//Open MySQL connection
//Get the data you want into a string variable called $info
print <<< END
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ziks</title>
<link href="CSS/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(Images/twe_background-1920x1080.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
... (rest of HTML excluded for brevity)
END;
?>
```

Simply put the $info variable where ever you want the data to appear in the HTML data.

The construct:

```
print <<< END
<<<what you want to print>>>
END;
```

is called a "heredoc" and is very handy.

I have not described how to actually get the data from the database since your question seemed more about the process of using PHP to output HTML with data from a database. Look at the PDO documentation ([PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo)) to quickly get up to speed on DB access in PHP.

Comment: Why use heredoc when you can just use php tags ( `?><html><?php ` ) ?  Also , how is that related to mysql ?

Comment: @t.m.adam  I like this format because it's much easier to read and maintain. Having a number of short tags sprinkled throughout the code is ugly and harder to see what's going on. In this case there is only two places where you would need to use the short tags. It's a personal preference. If you look at my answer I did specifically answer the MySQL detailed coding answer. That is easily answered by any number of PHP/MySQL coding tutorials. As I said, I saw the question as more of a how do I use PHP to output HTML (or create the equivalent to his index.html file).

Comment: Ok , i see .  I use tags , or just embed variables in strings , but as you said that's a matter of personal preference

Comment: @mlewis54 thanks for the reply, But my issue is that I don't know if my server (WebIOPi) allows me to run php! I know for sure how to direct it to utilize index.html and run it. I'm using raspberry pi 3 with php plugin got MySQL. Is it not possible to just have php code directly into the index.html without need of multiple index.php and other files?

Comment: I believe there are some kludges to that allow you to run php as an html file that involve .htaccess file rules. I am not familiar with Webliopi as a web server beyond what I've read. Since it seemed very Python oriiented I haven't paid much attention to it.. I would suggest using NGINX or even apache. I have several severs set up with NGINX on on  Raspberry PI 3's they work fast and can support a ton of connections. There are a number of great features such as reverse proxies. It's fairly easy to set up. All that being said you can google running your web server with PHP programs.

Comment: @mlewis54 I think I have to switch to phpmyadmin instead of webiopi which can run both php as well as html.